# How is mockk's allAny() used

Tags: kotlin, mockk

I can't find any documentation on `allAny()` that I can understand. The [official](https://mockk.io/) documentation describes it as a "special matcher that uses any() instead of eq() for matchers that are provided as simple arguments". I don't understand what that means.

I have a line that goes

```
every { mockObject.method(any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any(), any()) } returns 0
```

I thought `allAny()` might be able to replace repeated use of `any()`, but of course `mockObject.method(allAny())` is a syntax error because there are too few parameters.

So what is the use of `allAny()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mockk is a fantastic library but some examples in the official documentation are not providing the original mocked class. That leads to ambiguity. The documentation did not help much.

Let's assume that `Car` class has a method `fun accelerate(fromSpeed: Int, toSpeed: Int)`.
In this case, using `allAny()` paramater will give a syntax error as you mentionned.

However, compiler will not complain if our `accelerate` method has a default value for `toSpeed` or `fromSpeed`.

```kotlin
fun accelerate(fromSpeed: Int, toSpeed: Int = 100) { /* ... */ }
```

Let's have a test like below.

```kotlin
val car = mockk<Car>(relaxed = true)
car.accelerate(fromSpeed = 10, toSpeed = 20)
car.accelerate(fromSpeed = 30)

// will pass
verify(atLeast = 2) { car.accelerate(allAny()) }

// will not pass
verify(atLeast = 2) { car.accelerate(any()) }

confirmVerified(car)
```

`allAny` will pass seamlessly but `any` will not. `any` is accepting all values for `fromSpeed` but not for `toSpeed`.

```kotlin
Verification failed: call 1 of 1: Car(#1).accelerate(any(), eq(100))). 1 matching calls found, but needs at least 2 calls
Calls:
1) Car(#1).accelerate(10, 20)
2) Car(#1).accelerate(30, 100)
```

Hope it helps.